# Relative path to AppleScript exported as .app

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript exported as a .app file because I need it to run on log in.

This is my code:

```
repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with desktopNumber from 1 to count of desktops
            tell desktop desktopNumber
                set picture to "~/Desktop/script/img.jpg"
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end repeat
```

The path to the script is ~/Desktop/script/script.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt

I'd like to put the image in the Resources folder as well and make the path relative so i can put the folder anywhere without changing my script so I tried

```
set desktopPicture to ((container of container of (path to me)) as text) & "/img.jpg"
repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with desktopNumber from 1 to count of desktops
            tell desktop desktopNumber
                set picture to desktopPicture
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end repeat
```

But that gives me the error `Can’t make container of container of alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:Me:Desktop:script:script.app:Contents:Resources:Scripts:main.scpt\" into type text.`

Answer (score 0):

`System Events` is not able to expand the tilde `~`.

If you want to refer to `~/Desktop/script/img.jpg` using relative paths you could use

```
tell application "System Events" to set desktopPicture to file "img.jpg" of folder "script" of desktop folder
```

or

```
set desktopPicture to alias ((path to desktop folder as text) & "script:img.jpg")
```

Consider that in both cases AppleScript will throw an error if the file does not exist.